# How do I build a parameterized third-party library in cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a project in which I have a third party library checked out as a git submodule. The third party library is just source code with no build system. In addition, The third party library must configured on a per-executable basis by way of compiler definitions and selectively compiling only the parts of the library that I need. I use this library in a lot of different repositories, so I want to make a reusable component to generate an instantiation of the library for any particular executable.

The way I've currently attempted this is by creating a `generate_thirdparty.cmake`. This file looks something like this:

```
function(generate_thirdparty parameters)
    # several calls to add_library for the different components of this third party library
    # the generated libraries depend on the parameters argument
    # the parameters configure compile definitions and which source files are compiled
endfunction()
```

Then in my project `CMakeLists.txt` I have something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(test C)

include(generate_thirdparty.cmake)
set(parameters <some parameters here>)
generate_thirdparty(${parameters})

add_executable(my_exe main.c)
target_link_libraries(my_exe <library names from generate_thirdparty>)
```

It seems like what I have works, but I'm confused on how you're *supposed* to do this. I've read through other posts and seen people suggest using `find_package` or `ExternalProject_add`. Given a third party repository that contains source code and no build system, which you have no control over, how do you create a reusable way to build that library, especially in the case that the library must be parameterized any given executable?

EDIT: I would like to have the flexibility to have multiple instantiations of the library in the same project.

Comment: When you say "per-project" basis, does that mean that multiple configurations of the library are _not_ used within a single CMake build (or at least not within a single subdirectory)?

Comment: I meant a per-executable basis. I may have several executables that use different configurations of the same library.

Comment: When you say that you "use this library in a lot of different projects", does that mean entirely separate repositories?

Comment: Again, sorry for the bad wording. I use this library in a lot of separate repositories. In each repository, I have the library as a submodule. In each repository, I have a cmake project that builds multiple executables. Each executable may use a different instantiation of the library.

Comment: Okay, thanks, just trying to get an accurate view of your scenario / requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's sum up:

1. The third-party library does *not* provide its own build.
2. You need many instantiations of the library within a single build.
3. You use these instantiations across multiple different repositories.

I think you're pretty much taking the right approach. Let's call the third-party library `libFoo` for brevity. Here's what I think you should do...

1. Create a *wrapper* repository for `libFoo` that contains a `FindFoo.cmake` file and the actual `foo` repository submodule next to it. This is to avoid the contents of `FindFoo.cmake` from being independently versioned across your various projects.
2. Include the *wrapper* as your submodule in dependent projects, say in the directory `third_party/foo_wrapper`
3. In those dependent projects, write:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/foo_wrapper")
find_package(Foo REQUIRED)

generate_foo(config1 ...)
generate_foo(config2 ...)

add_executable(app1 src/app1/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app1 PRIVATE foo::config1)

add_executable(app2 src/app2/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app2 PRIVATE foo::config2)
```

4. The contents of `FindFoo.cmake` will simply be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

function(generate_foo target)
   # Use CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR to reference foo's source files
   # for example:

   set(sources "src/src1.cpp" "src/src2.cpp" ...)
   list(TRANSFORM sources PREPEND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR}/foo/")

   add_library(${target} ${sources})
   add_library(foo::${target} ALIAS ${target})

   # Do other things with ARGN
endfunction()

# Define a version for this dependency + script combo.
set(Foo_VERSION 0.1.0)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Foo VERSION_VAR Foo_VERSION
                                  HANDLE_COMPONENTS)
```

The `CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR` is the absolute path to the file containing the function being called. Remember that this is the root of your *wrapper* repository, so the actual sources for `libFoo` will be in the adjacent `foo` directory. `list(TRANSFORM)` lets us write relative paths in the sources list that get converted to absolute paths for the sake of `add_library` (passing a relative path to `add_library` would be relative to the *caller's* source directory).

I also create an `ALIAS` target so that callers of `generate_foo` can link to the alias. This is important because CMake considers names that contain `::` to be targets when a library is expected. This very helpfully turns typos from unintended linker flags into configure-time "target not found" errors.

Then we define the function like normal and call the `find_package_handle_standard_args` to handle `find_package` arguments like `REQUIRED`, `COMPONENTS` (even just to check that none were incorrectly specified), and `VERSION`. See the docs for it, here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html

Comment: Glad to see I was on the right track. How does `find_package_handle_standard_args` determine what components were success and what ones weren't? i.e. if the user passed in an invalid argument.

Comment: @JeffL - If you manually set `Foo_<COMPONENT>_FOUND` to something truthy, it will consider `<COMPONENT>` to be "found". If the user calls `find_package(Foo REQUIRED COMPONENTS Bar)` then since `Foo_Bar_FOUND` is unset, the call to `find_package` will fail with a message stating that `Bar` was not found.